# Unable to install a package called 'hemp' in R

Tags: r

I am new to learning R and i get the following error while installing the package called 'hemp'. Its a package which is used in psychometric analysis. Can anyone tell me what causes this errror?

```
Downloading GitHub repo cddesja/hemp@master
    Installing 1 packages: nloptr
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/UJJWAL/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    
      There is a binary version available but the
      source version is later:
            binary  source needs_compilation
    nloptr 1.2.2.1 1.2.2.2              TRUE
    
    installing the source package ‘nloptr’
    
    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nloptr_1.2.2.2.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2450931 bytes (2.3 MB)
    downloaded 2.3 MB
    
    * installing *source* package 'nloptr' ...
    ** package 'nloptr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** using staged installation
    
       **********************************************
       WARNING: this package has a configure script
             It probably needs manual configuration
       **********************************************
    
    
    ** libs
    
    *** arch - i386
    /mingw32/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.2/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
    /mingw32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.2/include" -DNDEBUG       -I"/i386/include"   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c init_nloptr.c -o init_nloptr.o
    init_nloptr.c:35:10: fatal error: nlopt.h: No such file or directory
     #include "nlopt.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:222: init_nloptr.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'nloptr'
    * removing 'C:/Users/UJJWAL/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/nloptr'
    Error: Failed to install 'hemp' from GitHub:
      (converted from warning) installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try adding ‘dep = TRUE’ in your line of code when installing, but agree with the person below stating nloptr needs installed as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it wouldbe a little harder to install `nloptr` on Windows. It require `nlopt` to be installed first. See this for more info: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/nloptr.html